# Dividing a time.Duration in Golang

Tags: go

At present, the `time` package in Go has no 'divide' function or anything similar.  You can divide a time.Duration by some other value, but it requires a fair bit of casting.  Is there any easy/obvious way to divide a time.Duration by something in Go that I'm not seeing?  (I know you can divide by a numeric constant, but I need to do it on a dynamic basis.)  I'm planning on submitting a issue/feature request to add a basic 'divide' function to the `time` package, but I wanted to ask here first in case I'm missing some easy way to do this kind of division.

Comment: You need to give specific, real examples of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Any update on submitting a feature request? I agree this would be handy for e.g. finding the mean execution time of a function.

Answer (score 8):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> There is no definition for units of Day or larger to avoid confusion
>   across daylight savings time zone transitions.
>
> To count the number of units in a Duration, divide:
>
> ```
> second := time.Second
> fmt.Print(int64(second/time.Millisecond)) // prints 1000
> ```
>
> To convert an integer number of units to a Duration, multiply:
>
> ```
> seconds := 10
> fmt.Print(time.Duration(seconds)*time.Second) // prints 10s
>
> const (
>         Nanosecond  Duration = 1
>         Microsecond          = 1000 * Nanosecond
>         Millisecond          = 1000 * Microsecond
>         Second               = 1000 * Millisecond
>         Minute               = 60 * Second
>         Hour                 = 60 * Minute
> )
> ```
>
> [type Duration](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration)
>
> A Duration represents the elapsed time between two instants as an
>   int64 nanosecond count. The representation limits the largest
>   representable duration to approximately 290 years.
>
> ```
> type Duration int64
> ```

---

Division and multiplication of `time.Duration` is described in the Go `time` package documentation.

Comment: Because it's just an `int64` you can also divide it by any integer constant, e.g. `someDuration / 2` is perfectly legal.

Comment: The example given in the `time` package indicates how to count the number of units in a Duration- not, for instance, get a duration that's 1/13 as long as the original one.  I know you can do it by casting both the `time.Duration` and the divisor into `int64`, doing the division, and then calling `time.Duration(result)`.  I'm just a bit surprised that `time` doesn't have a "Divide" method or something similar.

Comment: @PatrickJones you only need one cast: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77811092/473672

Answer (score 2):

> I know you can divide by a numeric constant, but I need to do it on a dynamic basis.

To divide a duration by a *non*-constant integer, just cast that integer to `time.Duration`. Only one cast is required. For example:

```golang
threeHours := 3 * time.Hour
six := 6

halfHour := threeHours / time.Duration(six)

fmt.Println(halfHour) // prints "30m0s"
```

The reason that this works is that `Duration` is an integer type: it has underlying type `int64`, where the integer is the number of nanoseconds. In Go, you can do arithmetic with any numeric type, as long as both operands have the same type.

As you've observed, you don't need the cast when you have a numeric *constant*. That's because an integer constant can be implicitly converted to any integer type. (This is the same reason that we can write `3 * time.Hour` to begin with: that's actually equivalent to `time.Duration(3) * time.Hour`.)

Comment: I don't think this gives you a Duration, does it?

Comment: @ruakh I'm using it myself and it works. This printout prints the divided duration with the right unit: https://github.com/walles/moar/blob/94a1f267c31fc7582e52c590d0341d243573a8c2/m/reader.go#L336

Comment: OK, I've tested, and you're right! So, this is clearly the best answer. (+1) I've taken the liberty of editing the answer to explain what's actually going on, since judging from what everyone else has written on this page, I'm clearly not the only person who doesn't find it intuitive. (I assumed some sort of [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) was going on, where a duration times a dimensionless number was a duration; but no, durations are actually dimensionless, and a duration times a duration is a duration.)

Answer (score -3):

If the divisor is a multiple of two, you can use shifting instead, without any
casting:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   n := 1
   d := time.Minute >> n
   fmt.Println(d) // 30s
}
```